# Image changes on hover, but not on Firefox

Tags: html, css

```css
#help {height: 127px; width: 127px}
#help:hover {content: url('LINK'); height: 127px; width: 127px}
```

```html
<a href="link"><img src="imagelink" id="help"></a>
```

This works fine for me, but only on Chrome. Doesn't seem like it works on Firefox, the "hover" image doesn't appear.

Comment: You can only use `content` on pseudo-elements, like `::before` and `::after`

Comment: WOW! It really works in Chrome!!!

Answer (score 3):

The CSS `content` attribute can only be used with *Pseudo Elements* like `::before` and `::after`.

Per MDN:

> The *content* CSS property is used with the **::before and ::after pseudo-elements** to generate content in an element. Objects inserted using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.
>
> **Initial value:**    *normal*
>
> **Applies to:**   *::before and ::after pseudo-elements*

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

---

For a fix, as Ballu suggests in his answer, you may want to make the image a `background-image` in CSS instead of an `<img>` element in the HTML. You can then change the `background-image` attribute on `:hover` instead of the `content` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **background** not **content**.

```
#help:hover {background: url('LINK'); height: 127px; width: 127px}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you already defined width and height on normal selector then you don't need to also defined on hover selector.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Ballu's answer above. This works in Firefox too.

```css
#help {background: url(http://placekitten.com/127/127);height: 127px; width: 127px; display: inline-block}
#help:hover {background: url('http://lorempixel.com/127/127/')}
```

```html
<a href="link" id="help"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use right metod, it set image trough background-image and change him state for hover